# Nuitka - описание свойств EXE файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

Как с помощью Nuitka можно задать описание свойств EXE?

В pyinstaller есть для этого ключ --version-file и потом указываешь путь к файлу где все данные прописаны об EXE (Кто сделал ПО, как версия и т.д)

Код файла Version ПО:

```
# UTF-8
#
# For more details about fixed file info 'ffi' see:
# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997.aspx
VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
# filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
# Set not needed items to zero 0.
filevers=(1, 2, 5, 30920),
prodvers=(1, 2, 5, 30920),
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the valid bits 'flags'r
mask=0x3f,
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file.
flags=0x0,
# The operating system for which this file was designed.
# 0x4 - NT and there is no need to change it.
OS=0x4,
# The general type of file.
# 0x1 - the file is an application.
fileType=0x1,
# The function of the file.
# 0x0 - the function is not defined for this fileType
subtype=0x0,
# Creation date and time stamp.
date=(0, 0)
),
  kids=[
StringFileInfo(
  [
  StringTable(
    u'040904B0',
    [StringStruct(u'CompanyName', u'2021 WINDOWS CORP'),
    StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'Downloading'),
    StringStruct(u'FileVersion', u'1.2.5'),
    StringStruct(u'InternalName', u'Downloading'),
    StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'Copyright (c) 2021 WINDOWS CORP'),
    StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'Downloading.exe'),
    StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'Downloading'),
    StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'1.2.5')])
  ]), 
VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1049, 1200])])
  ]
)
```

А вот какой ключ отвечает за данное действие в Nuitka не совсем понятно и как это можно в принципе сделать?

Comment: @insolor - огромное спасибо за столь хороший ответ

Comment: Оформил ответом

Answer (score 1):

В nuitka сходу такой функциональности не нашел (возможно есть, но нужно хорошо покопаться в документации). Можно попробовать написать issue автору проекта: https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues

Поковырял исходники PyInstaller, можно из него вызвать прописывание версии на готовом экзешнике, примерно такой скрипт получается:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.win32 import versioninfo
 
versioninfo.SetVersion("exe_file.exe", "version_info_file")
```

Вместо у `exe_file.exe` и `version_info_file` указываете фактические имена экзешника и вашего файла версии.

Т.е. сначала собираете exe файл с помощью nuitka, а потом в готовый exe прописываете версию с помощью pyinstaller.